# Will xcode 6 GM work with OSX Yosemite Beta 8?

Tags: xcode, macos

I want to update to OSX Yosemite Beta 8 from Mountain Lion but I want to be able to upload apps through the new software. Does Xcode 6 GM work with Yosemite DP8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Xcode 6 GM runs fine on OS X 10.10 (including DP8)...

That being said, keep in mind that Xcode 6 GM does not actually include the OS X 10.10 SDK. Only the 10.9 SDK is available.

For iOS development, everything's fine, as the iOS 8 SDK is available in the GM, and as apps can be submitted to the AppStore.

But for OS X 10.10 development, you'll have to use Xcode 6.1, available in beta from the developer center.

And by the way, Xcode 5.1 also runs fine on Yosemite (except a few UI bugs).

**EDIT**

To answer your comment, you can use Xcode 6 GM to submit iOS applications (including iOS 8).
For OS X apps, the GM will allow you to submit Mac apps using the OS X 10.9 SDK.

But For Mac apps using the OS X 10.10 SDK, you'll have to wait for the 6.1 GM, which should be available in a few weeks.
At the moment, only the 6.1 beta includes the OS X 10.10 SDK, and as it's a beta, you won't be allowed to submit apps to the AppStore.

Note that this only applies to the AppStore submission. DeveloperID signed applications can be built with the 6.1 beta.

Comment: If I get OSX 10.10 I can use Xcode 6, but you didn't answer my question, will I be able to send my apps to the app store with the Xcode 6 GM or Xcode 6.1 beta. I got confused when you said But for OS X 10.10 development, you'll have to use Xcode 6.1, available in beta from the developer center, why will I need to use it?

Comment: Sure, you can... It works perfectly, and you can submit iOS 8 and OS X 10.9 apps to the AppStore...

Comment: OS X 10.10 apps cannot be submitted to the Mac AppStore at the moment. You'll have to wait for the 6.1 GM.

Comment: So should I just download Mavericks?

Comment: I just make iphone apps, So osx yosemite will allow me to submit ios apps but not mac apps....

Comment: Yes... Yosemite DP8 and Xcode 6 GM are fine for iOS, including AppStore submission, as I said. The only issue is for Mac apps using the OS X 10.10 SDK, but if you're only developing iOS apps, you'll be just fine... You can install Yosemite and Xcode 6 GM, everything will work as expected.

Comment: Ok thanks alot, One last question. Will all of my apps on xcode 5.1 and all of my softwares be carried over to yosemite, (nothing deleted)?

Comment: That's another topic, but DP8 is nearly a GM... So no worries... Simply update your OS, and you'll be ready to go... And as a developer trying beta software, I can assume you have backups, right?